# Calculating the radius of convergence for a power series with coefficients fulfilling $c_{j+2} = \frac{j^2+j-L}{(j+1)(j+2)}c_j$, $L \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am considering the power series $y(x) := \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} c_jx^j$. The coefficients fulfill

\begin{align}
c_0 = 0, \quad c_1 = 1 \quad \text{ and } \quad  c_{j+2} = \frac{j^2+j-L}{(j+1)(j+2)}c_j,
\end{align}

$L \in \mathbb{R}$ being a constant.

I want to compute the radius of convergence $R$ of this power series and was wondering whether I can simply do this by the following naive calculation:

\begin{align}
R := \lim_{j \to \infty} \left|\frac{c_j}{c_{j+2}}\right| = \lim_{j \to \infty} \left|\frac{(j+1)(j+2)}{j^2+j-L}\right|= 1.
\end{align}

I am unsure because usually the formula for $R$ is given by $R := \lim_{j \to \infty} \left|\frac{c_j}{c_{j+1}}\right|$ but here we have the case that every coefficient with even index $j$ is $0$.

(In fact, the radius of convergence $R$ of this power series should indeed be $R=1$.)

Comment: You can simply reindex the sum to not include the even elements. Your analysis then holds.

Comment: Just for your curiosity : $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j\,x^j=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(3-\sqrt{4 L+1}\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{4 L+1}+3\right);\frac{3}{2};x^2\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function. I faced this problem many years ago and it is a very interesting function.